# How do you have a window that has no icon in the tasktray?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I found the windows style WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW but this changes the title bar. Is there a way to not have the tasktray icon but keep the normal window titlebar?

Comment: What if the user minimizes your window? How do you expect they will get it back?

Comment: You're right. A bad idea. Disregard this question.

Comment: Someone delete this question please.

Comment: You can delete it yourself, by clicking on "delete" just between your question tags and the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually do want to do this if you have added an alternate means to restore the window - for example placing an icon in the notification tray.

The usual way of ensuring the taskbar does not display your window is to create it with a hidden parent window. Whenever a window has a parent, the parent window is used to create the button - hidden windows are not shown on the taskbar.

Also, `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` should be removed as that performs the opposite hint to the shell and forces the window onto the taskbar even if it would otherwise not have been shown.